# Gitk don't work because of strange error macOS 11 or later required

Tags: git, macos, gitk

When starting gitk command line getting the error. It's strange because I have newest version of Mac OS 11.1 I just upgraded git but it doesn't helped. Any ideas what to do?

````
macOS 11 or later required !
/usr/bin/wish: line 2: 50965 Abort trap: 6           "$(dirname $0)/../../System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/Wish.app/Contents/MacOS/Wish" "$@"```
````

Comment: Your Mac has mismatched versions of the OS and the `wish` command. Why that is the case is a mystery to me, but the problem isn't Git, it's with the installed `wish` vs the installed Tcl/Tk. (Since `wish` is *part of* the tcl/tk system, they're not supposed to get out of sync.)

Comment: I running `brew install tcl` then it's working now. Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Solved it by running `brew install tcl`

Answer (score 2):

I have seen the most popular answer:

> Solved it by running `brew install tcl`

But after I done this, `gitk` still not work, I have two versions of wish installed:

```sh
$ type -a wish
$ wish is /usr/local/bin/wish
$ wish is /usr/bin/wish
```

Finally I found my solution:
I edit my **.zshrc** file, add alias for `gitk`:

```sh
alias gitk="/usr/local/bin/wish $(which gitk)"
```

Answer (score 0):

LiuJQ's solution works. It's indeed the `wish` problem. I fixed by adding alias for `gitk` by adding the following line in `~/.bashrc`.

```
alias gitk="/usr/local/bin/wish $(which gitk)"
```

Note: you need to reopen the terminal for this to take effect.